# Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, rest, lambda, https

I'm working on a REST API that itself makes requests to another REST API -- basically, it provides a more convenient interface and also some extra functionality. Let's call my REST API **X** and the REST API to which my API calls **Y**.

Whenever I make requests to the endpoints of **Y** on my machine with cURL, REST Client, etc; all requests are successful. Like I mentioned, my API **X** is acting as a wrapper to **Y**, so when I upload my API to aws Lambda and create the respective endpoints in API Gateway, when I make a request to one of the endpoints I get this message:

> Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host:
> X.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com. is not in the cert's altnames:
> DNS:somehostname.com

So far, I have uploaded two lambdas with their respective endpoints, and the problem above only seems to be happening for one of the endpoints (the request to the other endpoint happens without problem).

I would like to know why this is happening and if this is a problem on my side? Meaning, is there something I am forgetting or something I can do -- except bypassing some security mechanism -- to fix this on my side? Whenever I make requests to the original API **Y** on my machine I'm not getting any errors so I'm a bit puzzled by this.

Comment: To be clear - are you trying to access something like `api.example.com` with the calls being routed through API Gateway / Lambda?

Comment: @stdunbar Yes. That's exactly it. Is this problem being caused because the security certificates on the side of AWS don't match the security certificates from `api.example.com` ?

Comment: And do you have any control over the hosting and SSL certificates of "API Y"?

Comment: @stdunbar I don't. Do I take from your question that the error must be because there's a mismatch between the SSL certificates associated to the hosting of "api Y" ??? And if that's the case I can't do much about it ?

Comment: For the impatient: ***it's the `Host` header.*** Don't send API Y the same `Host` header that the client sent to API X.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're missing how SSL certificates work.  Depending on how the certificate is setup for "API Y" you can't just connect to a different server and have it work.  While you are conceptually a proxy to the real back end from the client perspective, you're a totally different host and the SSL certificate is for "API Y" only.

This is the same reason that you can't decide that you want to have an API named `trustme.google.com` - you don't have control over the `google.com` domain (presumably).

If there is a way to change the hostname that your client connections are using (to something like `proxy.yourdomain.tld`) then you can setup an SSL certificate for that domain and things should work.  However, at that point you may run into CORS issues - post again if you have that issue.

AWS [documents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) how to setup your own SSL certificate for API gateway.  It's pretty easy though if you have an existing certificate you may need to use the AWS certificate manager to get a (free) certificate for your API.

Update 03/10/2022: Before your proxy hands off the request to the real backend service, make sure to set `Host` header to the hostname of the real service, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host).

Comment: I must definitely be missing something. When I log into the aws console and test the lambda functions (that are proxying the requests to the other api) directly from api gateway, the responses are fine. The problem comes up when I try to make the request to API Gateway, and that's when I get the error message I  posted above.

Answer (score 1):

I also developed a `HTTP client -> APIG endpoint -> Lambda -> Host` application, where the `Lambda` acts as a proxy between the client and the 3rd party Host. My Lambda is written in Node.js. I was getting this same exact error when the Lambda tried to invoke the 3rd party Host,

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "body": "Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: zyxfghsk.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.somehost.com, DNS:somehost.com"
}
```

My setup uses Lambda Proxy integration with APIG, and I pass the set of HTTP headers from the client as-is to the 3rd party Host. I noticed the headers contained header `Host: zyxfghsk.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`, which I think comes from the client. So in the Lambda code, right before passing the request to the 3rd party Host, I just simply delete the `Host` header from the request, and the problem went away. Another approach I was trying earlier, which also works, but not as ideal is that I was setting `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` in the Node.js environment, which effectively disables SSL certificate validation by Node.js.
I believe, though not 100% certain, that in my case at least the error was getting thrown by Node.js certificate validation.

Update 03/10/2022: Before your proxy hands off the request to the real backend service, make sure to set `Host` header to the hostname of the real service, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host).

Comment: This answer exactly described my problem. My proxy was foolishly copying all the headers from the client to API Y, including the `Host` header, so when Node made the request to API Y with `Host` set to API X, of course Node was upset. In my case I simply copied the one header from the client request that API Y actually cared about. Thanks!